# Google Sheets concatenate lines from multiline cells

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

How can I concatenate lines from two (or more) multiline cells like this?
[image: multiline concat]

so that column C generated by something like:

=concatenate(A1{one line}, " is a ", B1{one line})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? I think that there are several answers. So please think of this as one of them.

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10))&" is a "&SPLIT(B1,CHAR(10))))
```

1. Split "A1" and "B1" by "CHAR(10)". I used "CHAR(10)" as the line break.
2. Add " is a " to the splitted "A1" and "B1".
3. Concatenate them using "JOIN()". The delimiter is "CHAR(10)".

#### Result :

[image]

#### Reference :

- [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.